# Collect data from an user during a workflow and pass these data into the correct field of the list the workflow runs on

Tags: workflow, links-list

I have a SP list "Requests" to track customer requests in which different types of data is stored, e.g. dates. I want to create a workflow on this list which sends an email to the responsible person when a new request is set up. This email should contain a link to a task-list in which the person should put in a date, for example "Date Request Received". This date should then be stored in the original list "Requests" which also has a field called "Date Request Received". How can this be done? 
I am new to SP and SPD and a detailed solution would be great.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you already tried playing around with SharePoint Designer and attempted to create this workflow? If so, where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the ask Task Actions "Collect Data from a User" and have the "Date Request Received" as the field for the user to fill out in the task.

1. Under "data" name the task and create the field you want them to fill out.
2. "this user" will need to be the person or SP group it should go to
3. The workflow will automatically output the ID of the associated task to the "collect" variable.
4. Then set the field in the Requests list to the Date field the user had to fill out in the task.

   - Data source" "Association:Task List"
   - Field from source: [Date column you created in the task]
   - Return field as: Short Date
   - Field: ID
   - Value: Variable:collect

Comment: Can you specify step 4? Which action do I need to use and what do you mean with "Association:Task List"? I have no data source like this, which I could choose. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi JArthur :) I tried a few things and now it works! Thank you very much. You helped me a lot!