# Gathering input through list workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, workflow

I am trying to develop a workflow for a list that "travels" from one department to the next.  For example, sales would create a new item in the list and fill out the first couple fields.  The workflow would begin and route to engineering.  Engineering would fill out fields like "model number" and "lead time" and then route to the Contracts department.  Contracts would then fill in fields such as "payment terms" and "due date".  And so forth.  The routing from one department to the next would also constitute their respective approval.

All of the responses need to show up in the list view, but I don't want a user in a particular department to be allowed to fill in a field that should be completed by someone in another department.

I am relatively new to sharepoint designer, so please have mercy.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can look at the following blog to understand on how to collect the data from a SharePoint group or user.

[Collect data from an user during a workflow and pass these data into the correct field of the list the workflow runs on](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/139709/collect-data-from-an-user-during-a-workflow-and-pass-these-data-into-the-correct)